# filter_input GET

Tags: php, html, post, get

Estou precisando recuperar os valor do GET para realizar uma inserção no banco através do método post,porém ao realizar chamada da função através do submit,apresenta seguinte critica **"Call Stack".**

✓ Código

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(empty($_SESSION['id'])){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Área restrita. Faça login" ;
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    include_once("include/config.php");

    $btnOrca = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'btnOrca', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($btnOrca){
        echo "Entrou na função";

            //Query Insert
            $query = "INSERT INTO orcamento (num_orcamento, produto, qtde,valor_unitario,valor_total) VALUES ('".$_GET['num_orc']."', '".$_GET['produto']."', '".$_GET['qtde']."', '".$_GET['valor_unit']."','".$_GET['total']."')";

            //Connection BD
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if($result){
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "Orçamento Gravado com Sucesso.";
            }else{
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "Problema ao Gera Orçamento";
            }
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Compra</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <br><br><br>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo "<p style='color: red;'>".$_SESSION['msg']."</p>";
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
    ?>
    <p class="title">Orçamentos</p>
    <form method="get" action="" class="container" style="width: 400px;">
    <label for="orcamento">Numero do Orçamento:</label>
        <input type="number" id="num_orc" name="num_orc" min="1" value="1" class="form-control"/>   
        <br>    
        <label for="produto">Produto</label>
        <select id="produto" name="produto" class="form-control">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT id,descricao FROM produto";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                if($resultado){
                    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                        echo "<option value='".$linha['id']."'>".$linha['descricao']."</option>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="qtde">Quantidade: </label>
        <input type="number" id="qtde" name="qtde" min="1" value="1" class="form-control"/>
        <br>
        <label for="valor_unit">Valor unitário: </label>
        <input type="number" id="valor_unit" name="valor_unit" step="0.01" value="0.01" class="form-control" onblur="calcular()" />
        <br>
        <label for="total">Valor Total: </label>
        <input type="number" id="total" name="total" class="form-control" disabled/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnOrca" value="Gravar" />
    </form>
<!-- Javascript calcuclar Campo -->
<script>
function calcular() {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor_unit').value, 10);
  var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('qtde').value, 10);
  var mone = (n1 * n2);
  document.getElementById('total').value = mone;
}
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Erro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Mude aqui:

```
 $btnOrca = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'btnOrca', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($btnOrca){
    echo "Entrou na função";
```

Para:

```
i$btnOrca = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_DEFAULT);

if($btnOrca['btnOrca']){
// aqui vai o contudo do if.
}
```

sua query ficará assim:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO orcamento (num_orcamento, produto, qtde,valor_unitario,valor_total) VALUES ('".$btnOrca['num_orc']."', '".$btnOrca['produto']."', '".$btnOrca['qtde']."', '".$btnOrca['valor_unit']."','".$btnOrca['total']."')";
```

as vairaveis vindas do GET, podem ser pegas assim:
$btnOrca['nome do campo'], assim pode utiliza-las como precisar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Realizei sugestão das alterações,erro persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que está dando problema no insert do MySQL, os campos todos são de string mesmo? Se forem tenta dar um filtro para cada GET, talvez de certo. Agora se algum campo for integer, precisa passar o dado como numero e não como texto.

No MySQl quando vc coloca os valores entre aspas você insere como texto. 
Exemplo `'1'` é inserido como texto (string) e `1` sem aspas é inserido como numero (integer).

Talvez os filtros assim ajude:

```
$num_orc = trim(filter_var($_GET['num_orc'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$produto = trim(filter_var($_GET['produto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$qtde = trim(filter_var($_GET['qtde'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$valor_unit = trim(filter_var($_GET['valor_unit'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$total = trim(filter_var($_GET['total'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

$query = "INSERT INTO orcamento (num_orcamento, produto, qtde, valor_unitario, valor_total) VALUES ('{$num_orc}', '{$produto}', '{$qtde}', '{$valor_unit}','{$total}')";
```

Se forem do tipo integer, tente mudar `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` para `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`

exemplo:

`$num_orc = filter_var($_GET['num_orc'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

E no insert do mysql tire as aspas desse modo:

`... valor_total) VALUES ({$num_orc}, ...`

Espero que isso ajude a resolver seu problema. Caso continue dando erro, dê uma atualizada na pergunta com um novo print dos erros que aparecerem.